# Square bracket (tag) in search URL parameter is gone after human verification step

Tags: bug, captcha

Let's say I want to search for "mobile" with "android" tag, I use the following URL:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mobile+%5Bandroid%5D

This works fine.  However, if a Human Verification step is needed, the square bracket is dropped after the verification, the URL then becomes:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mobile+android&s=0f4f5d1c-...

Is there a way to preserve the square bracket after human verification?